# My way dealing with understanding structure of MouseJoint. Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I have a little problem.I'm making air hockey game. I want to have drag/droping player body  so that it can collides/give force to other object in PhysicsWorld but !
I do want my body(touching) to stick and move exacly like my finger(and still having force!)
The code I gave you below have almost the effect I want but when I move my finger it... "bounces" around the area I touched. How to make it to stick my finger and still count force?
Can someone help me what to change in this code? Thank you a lot :)!

```
private Body groundBody = null;
public MouseJoint createMouseJoint(AnimatedSprite box , float x, float y){
        final Body boxBody = this.mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findBodyByShape(box);


        float pixelToMeteRatio=64;
    Vector2 v =boxBody.getWorldPoint(new Vector2(x/pixelToMeteRatio, y/pixelToMeteRatio));

        MouseJointDef mjd = new MouseJointDef();
        mjd.bodyA                               = groundBody;
        mjd.bodyB                               = boxBody;
        mjd.dampingRatio                = 1f;
        mjd.frequencyHz             = 30;
        mjd.maxForce                    = (float) (200.0f * boxBody.getMass());
        mjd.collideConnected            = true;
        mjd.target.set(v);
        return (MouseJoint) this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(mjd);
}

MouseJoint mjActive = null;
private float pixelToMeteRatio = PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(
                final TouchEvent        pSceneTouchEvent,
                final ITouchArea        pTouchArea      ,
                final float             pTouchAreaLocalX,
                final float             pTouchAreaLocalY )
{

        if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                this.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        final AnimatedSprite face = (AnimatedSprite)pTouchArea; //The touched body
                        //If we have a active MouseJoint, we are just moving arround don't create an 2nd one.
                        if( mjActive == null)
                        {
                                Vector2 vector = new Vector2(pTouchAreaLocalX/pixelToMeteRatio,pTouchAreaLocalY/pixelToMeteRatio);
                                //=====================================
                                // GROUNDBODY - Used for the MouseJoint
                                //=====================================
                                BodyDef groundBodyDef = new BodyDef();
                                groundBodyDef.position.set(vector);
                                groundBody      = mPhysicsWorld.createBody(groundBodyDef);
                                //====================================
                                // CREATE THE MOUSEJOINT
                                //====================================
                                mjActive        = createMouseJoint(face, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
                        }
                }});

                return true;
        }

return false;
}


@Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

            if(this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {


            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                    this.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                            if( mjActive != null ){ //If the MJ is active move it ..

                                    // =========================================
                                    // MOVE THE MOUSEJOINT WITH THE FINGER..
                                    // =========================================
                                    Vector2 vec = new Vector2(pSceneTouchEvent.getX()/pixelToMeteRatio, pSceneTouchEvent.getY()/pixelToMeteRatio);
                                    mjActive.setTarget(vec);

                            }
                    }});
                    return true;
            }

            //===========================================
            // RELEASE THE FINGER FROM THE SCENE..
            //===========================================
            if(     pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP     ||     pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
              ) {

                    this.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {


                            if( mjActive != null )
                            {
                                    //======================================
                                    // DESTROY OUR MOUSEJOINT
                                    //======================================
                                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyJoint(mjActive);
                               //     groundBody.setTransform(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY(), groundBody.get);
                                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(groundBody);
                                    mjActive = null;
                            }

                    }});

         //         groundBody.setLinearVelocity(0,0);
                    return true;
            }
            }       
            return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweak the following parameters: dampingRatio, frequencyHz, maxForce. Also, lowering the body's mass should help. I think that setting the damping very close to 1, the frequency a bit higher and the force very high should do the trick.

Comment: not exacly, it still bounces when action is down around the anchor it recived

Comment: Setting the mass to zero does not help? Try changing the body type to kinematic while the user is touching it. That could cause other problems though.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for answers! But if u set mass to zero,   line      
mjd.maxForce   = (float) (200.0f * boxBody.getMass());
doesn't make any sense because, other object will collide but won't recive any force.

Comment: You can set the force independently on the body's mass.

Comment: Anyway, setting the force very high should solve the problem. What combinations of settings have you tried?